# Does CodeQL support edits on a call graph?

Tags: java, static-analysis, call-graph, codeql

I'm new to CodeQL and am reading [this tutorial](https://codeql.github.com/docs/codeql-language-guides/navigating-the-call-graph/) about how to query a Java call graph. It looks like CodeQL only supports read operations on the call graph.

If I hope to edit the call graph (e.g., add or delete an edge that represents method A calls method B) before querying, what can I do with CodeQL?

BTW, I'm familiar with [Soot](https://github.com/soot-oss/soot), which can read or edit a call graph with APIs. I am wondering if CodeQL also supports these features.

Answer (score 0):

No, CodeQL does not support editing the source or class files from which a CodeQL database was created. The CodeQL database is completely standalone (which allows you to [download an already created database and analyze it locally](https://lgtm.com/help/lgtm/running-queries-ide#download-codeql-database)).